# Different size rows in array literal Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I'm trying to do this in Google Sheets:

```
={{1}; {1, 1}}
```

and get the error In `ARRAY_LITERAL`, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.

My ultimate goal is to do something like this:

```
"title A"
IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet A", A:Z)...
"title B"
IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet B", A:Z)...
"title C"
IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet C", A:Z)...
etc...
```

Preferably the import range would ignore empty A rows as well. Each spreadsheet has different amount of columns and rows and they all change every once in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do it like this:

```
={{1, ""}; {1, 1}}
```

and for your `IMPORTRANGE` example it will be like:

```
={{"title A","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""}; 
 IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet1A:Z")}
```

but to avoid repeating of empty cells you can do:

```
={{"title A", SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 25), 2), 1, )};
 IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet1A:Z")}
```

which means: repeat (`REPT`) number 12 twenty-five times (because you need to cover range B:Z) this will give you number: 12121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212 and now you will `SPLIT` it every time there is number 2 so you will get 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 across 25 cells. and to get rid of those 1's you will `SUBSTITUTE` number one for nothing

or like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({{"title A", SUBSTITUTE(COLUMN(B:Z)^0, 1, )};
 IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet1A:Z")})
```

also don't forget to run every `IMPORTRANGE` separately before attempting your joint formula. you need to allow access to connect your spreadsheets with each unique `IMPORTRANGE`

---

```
={{"title A", SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 25), 2), 1, )};
 IMPORTRANGE("ID1", "Sheet1A:Z");
  {"title B", SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 25), 2), 1, )};
 IMPORTRANGE("ID2", "Sheet1A:Z");
  {"title C", SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 25), 2), 1, )};
 IMPORTRANGE("ID3", "Sheet1A:Z")}
```

to get rid of empty rows you could do something like:

```
=QUERY({{"title A", SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 25), 2), 1, )};
        IMPORTRANGE("ID1", "Sheet1A:Z");
        {"title B", SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 25), 2), 1, )};
        IMPORTRANGE("ID2", "Sheet1A:Z");
        {"title C", SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 25), 2), 1, )};
        IMPORTRANGE("ID3", "Sheet1A:Z")}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

Comment: why is the `SUBSTITUTE` necessary? Why not just do `SPLIT(REPT(" ,"), ",")`

Comment: @user12341234 to remove those 1's.